# Time on Email Template is Different from CRM item

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have a SuiteCRM 7.1. The date I entered on the CRM when put on a template is way off when it comes to the email template. Does anyone know or have experienced this? I already modified the date.timezone in the PHP cli.

[image: This is how it looks like from the email and the SuiteCRM itself]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time on SuiteCRM is stored in UTC on the database.

Whenever a date is rendered, user timezone is used to offset it properly.

I haven't used date-time in emails so I am speculating here, I think the CRM is showing the DB date without any formatting (due to the email nature, who knows the timezone of the receiver).

I guess that if your CRM is used in a single timezone, you can just create a few more fields in the CRM called  `date_entered_corrected` and just use `Workflows` to update the date everytime the field is modified to be adjusted to the receiver timezone.

Other trick is just storing the date and time as strings.

Comment: Thanks! I just made a new field that is exclusive for mail send outs and have it updated through the workflows. Thanks a bunch!